# win32: destroy a deskstop created with CreateDesktop

Tags: windows, pywin32, winapi

What's the opposite of `CreateDesktop()`? `CloseDesktop()` seems to only close the handle to the new desktop, but not to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, desktops are reference counted, so they're destroyed when nothing is using them anymore (and having an un-closed handle to one is included as "using").